# how to pass querystring values to swf?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash, query-string

This is driving me nuts... Based on my research I should be able to pass QueryString parameters directly to a swf object like so:

http://localhost:3000/SomeFlash/bin-debug/myFlash.swf?userId=827419

In the mxml oncreationcomplete method I have tried the following:

```
// oncreationcomplete method
    var userIdTest1:String = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters[0];
    var userIdTest2:String = Application.application.parameters.userId;
    var userIdTest3:String = this.parameters.userId;


    // External Interface
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("OnGameLoad", ClientParams);


// callback method
   protected function ClientParams(userId:String):void
   {
        this.userId = userId;           
   }
```

source
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf626ae-7feb.html

I am using Flashbuilder 4.5 with Flex 4.5.1 compiler. I am using a mxml with an html wrapper, but I am trying to pass the parameters via url to the swf directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of testing and some dumb luck I found that the following will work for getting querystring parameters.

// In the oncreationcomplete method

```
this.userId = this.parameters.userId;
```

Answer (score 2):

ExternalInterface is not available if you're launching the swf directly.

Likewise, I suspect that's the reason that the queryString is not available.

Try hitting the hosting HTML page instead.  (ie., http://localhost:3000/SomeFlash/bin-debug/myFlash.html?userId=827419)

Comment: Good idea, having a hosted HTML page is always a better idea generally. I can't think of a reason why to call the SWF directly in a browser other than for the sake of fast distribution to friends so they can try your project out.

Comment: The swf is used in a 3d application which uses swfs directly, so I can't have an html wrapper